# postMessage sent from extension has non-null source, indistinguishable from self-sent message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Chrome extensions are able to postMessage with a source and origin that matches the current window and origin, thereby making it impossible to distinguish between a self-sent message and a message sent by an extension.

**Dragon web extension** is creating the problem for other Gmail chrome extensions. Without installing the dragon extension, the extension that I am working on is going fine but as soon as the dragon extension is installed it conflicts with the mine Gmail extension and many others are also facing this problem.

the console has the following received message:

```
{"protocol":"nuanria_messaging","type":"request","messageId":0,"action":"requestSpeechHostStatus","responseRequired":false}
```

Reference: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=585335

Comment: The linked issue contains both a workable solution (i.e. use a token to check the origin of the message), and a "won't fix" resolution dating back to 2016. Not really sure what kind of answer you are expecting here on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Don't use postMessage in extensions, it's an anti-pattern, particularly for this type of problems. Use CustomEvent with a unique random event id when communicating between same-origin contexts, otherwise use postMessage only once with a dummy message and a **transferrable** port of MessageChannel, which you will then use for direct communication instead of targetWindow.postMessage.